# Laravel How to get access token on Youtube API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, youtube, youtube-api

I'm getting Token required error while already Enabled route option but still, it's not working.

by using this library : https://github.com/JoeDawson/youtube

[image]

could you help me to solve this problem?

## Code  :

```
class VideoController extends BaseController {

public function __construct(){

}

public function store(Request $request){

    $video = Youtube::upload($request->file("video")->getPathName(), [
        'title'       => 'My Video',
        'description' => 'This video is uploaded through API.',
        'tags'        => ['api', 'youtube'],
    ]);

    return $this->sendResponse($video);
} 
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code so we have an idea of how to help?  I'm guessing you need to follow the steps at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps specifically the "Obtaining OAuth 2.0 access tokens" section.

Comment: hi bro, your information isn't sufficient, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask a better question with more details

Comment: do you use https://github.com/joedawson/youtube package? if yes did you set Client ID and Client secret?

Comment: @user1669496 can u take look at the code, please .

Comment: @Ali Yes, i set them on (.env)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of that package you need to do these steps, because you may have problem with **refresh_token**  (I guess you don't have any token in your database which must be created after logging in google)

It's important that before you begin uploading a video, you have confirmed that you have a **refresh_token** in your database if not these steps have to be helpful.

1- Delete all of your tokens in the **youtube_access_tokens table**. 
2- Enable routes in **youtube.php**  
3- **Re-authenticate** with **Google**  
4- Check your **youtube_access_tokens table** and find the most **recent token**.  
5- Review the token and ensure a **refresh_token** exists.  
6- Disable authentication routes in **config/youtube.php**

briefly, for creating a token You need to visit your [Google console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and add your URL as the callback (localhost).
Then in your app, visit http://localhost:8000/youtube/auth - you will be redirected to Google and will be asked to log in. This is when you get a token and then you may not see that error again!

Comment: (step 3-...-6), but how to implement these steps in Laravel API, because I can't be redirected in the API

Comment: @AlgoVR read the added paragraph bro! and for the last step, you have to set false in that config file

Comment: @AlgoVR what happened?! Did you solve this? ask me any problem that you faced

Comment: i'm agree with u,  but actually i'm looking to handle these steps in the api, without redirecting the user !

Comment: i got this error : Error: redirect_uri_mismatch, when i try to open this url : http://localhost:8000/youtube/auth

Comment: @AlgoVR no need to redirect user every time, just one time you need to authorize your application with creating a token by the way I told you

Comment: I see, @Ali have you any ideas who can I test these on Postman

Comment: @AlgoVR clearly it means you don't have redirect URL or is wrong so Go to the console for your project and look under API Access. You should see your client ID & client secret there, along with a list of redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list and it should take some minutes to be work

Comment: @AlgoVR don't forget the redirect_uri in the config file which has to be as same as the URI you entered in google console developer

Comment: I got an error can u check these please : 
*config/youtube.php* : https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8G19.png

*ID clients OAuth 2.0* : https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Cyo.png

Comment: @AlgoVR review the answer!the Error ***an access token required*** is due to you don't have refresh key in ***youtube_access_tokens table***, am I right?! do you have any record in that table?so if not by /youtube/auth route you have to be redirected to google and be logged in and then in the redirect to your application the token will be inserted to that table, for the error ***redirect_uri_mismatch*** you should set redirect URI of the application in both Google and the config file(which not ok,set route which not set before)for set in google watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCLwdwx9xUs

Comment: awesome bro it's work now !!, but I can handle the auth google using React.js, and the API just upload the video. but I think in this case I need to save at first the access_token by getting it from React, at the end API will verify just the access_token if there exists in the database or not, without redirecting it via the API. is that makes sense !!

Comment: Yeah Yeah I'll do,  how can I get the information about the user for example : ( getUserByToken() )

Comment: ^_^, @Ali any suggestion about how to get the info

Comment: @AlgoVR please ask with more detail !  which user! which token?! I didn't understand the purpose

Comment: well, @Ali I mean by the token is the access_token stored in the database more specified *youtube_access_tokens* table , by this way I can get the info about the user via there access_token or not?

Comment: any suggestions !!

Comment: @AlgoVR by the token I don't think there is a way to get user info, it's somehow private! but you can get it from a middleware you set for every user login in or ask your user to send their information before authorize...for this new issue ask a new question

Comment: Thank You so much for your help and it was a better decision. ^_^